# What is the linq expression for that

Tags: linq

I do not know how to refactor this expression.

```
TreeViewItemNode FindNode(TreeViewItemNode nodeCollection)
{
    foreach (var child in nodeCollection.Children)
        {
            var found = FindNodeContainingVarId(child, varId);
            if (found != null)
                return found;
        }

   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First select the node and take the first found node or null if no node was found like:

```
TreeViewItemNode FindNode(TreeViewItemNode nodeCollection)
{
    return nodeCollection.Children
        .Select(child => FindNodeContainingVarId(child, varId).
        .FirstOrDefault(node => node != null);
}
```